# Overlapping Ctrl+Shift on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, manjaro

On my Manjaro system (KDE) I set Ctrl+Shift to change keyboard layout.
After this combination with Ctrl+Shift+n, Ctrl+Shift+p , etc not work in another applications.
Before, for  solve this problem I installed package xorg-server-bug865 from aur. 
But after upgrade system X not start and I was forced to uninstall xorg-server-bug865 & reinstall sddm.

Perhaps someone had the same problem and found a good solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug about shortcuts mapped to combinations which include each other.

For example, if we have `Ctrl+Shift` (for keyboard layout) and `Ctrl+Shift+N` (to open a new terminal), then we are practically unable to use the second shortcut; this is what happens:
Ctrl press (nothing happens)
Shift press (keyboard layout change)
N (a simple N appears, since a shortcut has already fired)

The expected behavior is to fire shortcuts on the release (not on press) of the special keys (ctrl,shift,alt, etc) This is a serious problem for bilingual layouts, typically using `Alt+Shift` or `Ctrl+Shift` for keyboard layout change.

It looks like the patch requires manual intervention. Do to the overriding of the `xorg-server.conf` file. 
It seems like this has been an issue that dates all the way back to **2004**